# Finding Next Valid Table

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

We are given a list of distances say distances = [2, 4, 1]. The number of tables is the length of distances + 1, so in our example we will have 4 tables. For every table we need to find the next valid table so that the distance between a table j and i is greater than or equal to 6 feet. If no such table exists then the next valid table for j is set to 0. In addition, the width of a single table is 1 foot. So in our example we have:

```
t1 -- t2 ---- t3 - t4
where a single dash represents 1ft.

Next valid table for t1 is 0
Next valid table for t2 is 0 
Next valid table for t3 is t1 because they share a distance of 7ft between them
Next valid table for t4 is t2 because they share a distance of 6ft between them
```

How do I figure out the next valid table for each table? I noticed that the first table was special because there is no other table before it so its next valid table will automatically be set to 0. I also found that there are subproblems that need to be solved (so I think I can do in a bottom-up dynamic programming fashion). The solution for the next table  will depend on the solution to its previous table. This is some logic I came up with:

```
if distance between table i and i-1 is >= 6:
    next valid table for i is i-1
elif table i-1 has a next valid, table i's next valid will be table (i-1) next valid + 1
else:
     # Stuck here on how to find the next valid table
```

I feel like I'm on the right track to get this O(n) but I need a little extra help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the table positions and maintain a pointer to the correct table that's an answer for the next i.

```
  2   4   1
0   3   8   10
t1  t2  t3  t4

t1 0  ptr 0
t2 0  ptr 0
t3 t1 ptr t1
t4 t2 ptr t2
```

The left pointer will at most be incremented `O(n)` times, and we'll use `O(n)` additional space.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'd use is not dynamic programming so much as keeping a trailing pointer that follows along a forward iteration over the distances list, hugging the `max_distance` gap specified by the parameter. This trailing pointer gets incremented whenever it can safely point to a new table and still satisfy the required distance gap. For every instruction, the pointer tells us which table is the "next" one (really, "previous" relative to a forward iteration but "next" relative to a backward iteration).

Everything else is a matter of bookkeeping to make sure this pointer is in the right place. This is the annoying part.

Time complexity is linear since the inner loop that pushes the back pointer along will never execute more than `n` times in total. Space complexity is O(1).

```
def next_valid_tables(dists, max_dist):

    # keeps track of the gap between the left index and the current table
    running_dist = 0

    # O(n), makes the coding easier but not a necessary expense
    dists = [0] + dists 

    left = 0
    result = []

    for i, dist in enumerate(dists):
        running_dist += dist

        # Move the left index forward as long as we can still
        # satisfy the running_dist >= max_dist requirement.
        # The - 1 and + 1s handle the width of a single table.
        while left < i and running_dist - dists[left] - 1 >= max_dist:
            running_dist -= dists[left] + 1
            left += 1

        running_dist += 1 # Add the width of this table

        # The left pointer now points at the nearest valid table 
        # (or 0) so it's the result for this element
        result.append(left)
    
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(next_valid_tables([2, 4, 1], 6)) # => [0, 0, 1, 2]
    # 1 2 3 4  <-- table idxes
    #  4 4 1   <-- dists
    # 0 1 2 2  <-- next table idxes

    print(next_valid_tables([4, 4, 1], 2)) # => [0, 1, 2, 2]
    # 1 2 3 4  <-- table idxes
    #  2 4 1   <-- dists
    # 0 1 2 2  <-- next table idxes

    print(next_valid_tables([2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6,], 6)) # => [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7]
    # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  <-- table idxes
    #  2 1 1 1 1 2 6   <-- dists
    # 0 0 0 1 1 2 4 7  <-- next table idxes
```